# Phase angles of a complex eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, nonlinear-eigenvalue

I have the following system for $\lambda \in \Bbb C, \lambda \neq 0$ and $\pmb{p},\pmb{q} \in \Bbb C^n$, $(\pmb{p}^T, \pmb{q}^T)\neq0$:

$$\begin{cases} F(\lambda) \pmb{p} - g(\lambda) \pmb{q} - \lambda \alpha\beta M^{-1}C \pmb{q} 
 = 0 \ , \\  g(\lambda) \pmb{p} + F(\lambda) \pmb{q} + k \alpha\beta M^{-1}C \pmb{p} 
 = 0 \ . \end{cases} $$
Where $F(\lambda) = \lambda^3 I + \lambda^2(\alpha I + \beta D) + \lambda \alpha \beta D$, $g(\lambda) =  \lambda^2\beta + \lambda \alpha \beta$,  $\alpha, \beta, k$ are positive scalars, $D,M$ are $n\times n$ diagonal matrices with positive elements on its diagonals, $C$ is $n\times n$ real positive semi-definite matrix (non-diagonal).

> For which matrix $D$ phase angles of $\pmb{p}$ are opposite to $\pmb{q}$ (namely, $p_k = \pm|p_k|e^{i\phi_k}$ and $q_k = \pm|q_k|e^{-i\phi_k}, \ k=1,\cdots,n$)?

I suspect it is valid only if $D = dI$. Because in this case, $F(\lambda) = [\lambda^3 + \lambda^2(\alpha I + \beta d) + \lambda \alpha \beta d]I = f(\lambda)I$ and $\pmb{p}$ will be an eigenvector of $M^{-1}C$. Further, $\pmb{q}= -\frac{g(\lambda) + k\alpha\beta\mu}{f(\lambda)} \pmb{p}$, where $\mu$ is the correspoding eigenvalue of $M^{-1}C$ such that difference between phase angles of $\pmb{p}$ and $\pmb{q}$ is $\phi_0 = \angle  \frac{g(\lambda) + k\alpha\beta\mu}{f(\lambda)}$, and the pair $(\pmb{p} = e^{-i\frac{\phi_0}{2}}\pmb{\psi}, \pmb{q}= - e^{-i\frac{\phi_0}{2}}\frac{g(\lambda) + k\alpha\beta\mu}{f(\lambda)}\pmb{\psi})$ with $M^{-1}C$ eigenvector $\pmb{\psi} \in \Bbb R^n$ will have the opposite phase angles. I do not know how to show $D=dI$ is necessary or find conterexample with $D\neq d I$.

Comment: Your condition on $\pmb p$ and $\pmb q$ is not obviously invariant under change of coordinates (which will change phase angles), so it would be quite surprising to me if the answer were invariant under change of coordinates.  (Incidentally, when distinguishing between the angle and the modulus, using $\pmb\psi$ for the *modulus* is an interesting choice!)